# Server did not read message from last client

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I need to simulate a distributed system.

There is a controller and *n* worker computers.

The controller tells the computers when to start, and the computers will start connecting to other computers using sockets. The controller is connecting to the computers using threads. The computer will connect to other computers using threads as well.

Once they are connected to each other, they will send events to each other until they have generated *x* events. Once they reach *x* events, the computer will send a **"Finish"** message to the controller saying that it's done generating events, but will continue reading events from other computers.

**My issue:** The computers have successfully sent the Finish message to controller, except the last computer in the system. According to the logs, the last computer did send the Finish message to the controller, but the controller did not receive it. The other computers successfully sent the finish message to the controller.

If you need more information, I would be glad to provide. I have been working on this for hours and have no clue.

Computer.java

```
package timetableexchange;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Computer {

    // Constant system capacity
    static final int MAX_SYSTEMS = 4;
    // Computer's time-stamp vector
    static Vector<Integer> timestamp = new Vector<Integer>();
    // Computer's ID
    static int identifier;
    // Computer's Event Count
    static int eventCount = 0;
    // Computer's isAlive check
    static boolean isAlive = true;

    // Socket to Controller
    Socket socketToController;
    PrintWriter outputToController;
    BufferedReader inputFromController;
    String textFromController;

    // Server Socket
    ServerSocket serverSocket;

    // Input and Output Clients
    static ArrayList<ClientSocket> outputClients = new ArrayList<ClientSocket>();
    static ArrayList<ClientConnection> inputClients = new ArrayList<ClientConnection>();

    // Log
    Log log;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Computer("127.0.0.1", 8000);
    }

    public Computer(String hostname, int port) throws IOException {
        // Initialize time-stamp
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SYSTEMS; ++i) {
            timestamp.add(0);
        }

        // Connect to Controller
        try {
            socketToController = new Socket(hostname, port);
            inputFromController = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketToController.getInputStream()));
            outputToController = new PrintWriter(socketToController.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Get Computer ID from Controller
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (inputFromController.ready()) {
                    textFromController = inputFromController.readLine();
                    identifier =  Integer.parseInt(textFromController);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        log = new Log("client" + identifier + ".txt");

        // Read start message
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (inputFromController.ready()) {
                    textFromController = inputFromController.readLine();
                    if (textFromController.equals("Start")) {
                        log.write("Computer is starting!");
                        break;
                    } 
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Instantiate server socket
        int socketPort = port + identifier + 1;
        // System.out.println(socketPort);
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketPort);

        log.write("Server Socket Instantiated");

        // Instantiate sockets for other server sockets (computers) to send
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SYSTEMS; ++i) {
            if (i != identifier) {
                Socket acceptedSocket = new Socket(hostname, port + i + 1);
                ClientSocket socketToComputer = new ClientSocket (acceptedSocket);
                outputClients.add(socketToComputer);
            }
        }

        log.write("Client Sockets Instantiated\n");

        // Accept sockets from server socket and add them into a list
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SYSTEMS - 1; ++i) {
            ClientConnection computerConn = new ClientConnection(serverSocket.accept());
            computerConn.start();
            inputClients.add(computerConn);
        }

        log.write("Server connected to clients");

        Random rand = new Random();

        // Generating events
        int temp;
        while (eventCount < 50) {
            log.write("Generating Event");
            int choice = rand.nextInt(5);
            if (choice == 0) {
                temp = timestamp.get(identifier);
                ++temp;
                timestamp.set(identifier, temp);
            } else {
                int randC = rand.nextInt(outputClients.size());
                ClientSocket cc = outputClients.get(randC);
                cc.out.writeObject(new Event(identifier, timestamp));
            }
            log.write(timestamp.toString());
            log.write("Done Generating Event");
            eventCount++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        log.write("Finished writing. Continue reading...");

        /**
         * ========THE ISSUE IS BELOW.===============
         */
        synchronized (outputToController) {
            outputToController.println("Finish");
            outputToController.flush();
        }

        log.write("Sent Finish Message " + identifier);

        // Wait for Tear Down Message
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (inputFromController.ready()) {
                    textFromController = inputFromController.readLine();
                    if (textFromController.equals("Tear Down")) {
                        log.write("Tearing down....");
                        isAlive = false;
                        break;
                    } 
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        log.write("Computer shutting off....");

    }

    // client socket class (organizing)
    public class ClientSocket {
        Socket socket;
        ObjectOutputStream out;
        ObjectInputStream in;

        public ClientSocket(Socket s) {
            try {
                this.socket = s;
                this.out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            log.write("Client Socket Created");
        }
    }

    // send event thread
    public class ClientConnection extends Thread {
        Socket socket;
        ObjectOutputStream out;
        ObjectInputStream in;
        Random rand = new Random();
        public ClientConnection(Socket s) {
            this.socket = s;
            try {
                out = new ObjectOutputStream (socket.getOutputStream());
                in = new ObjectInputStream (socket.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run () {
            while (isAlive) {
                log.write("Reading events");
                try {
                    Event event = (Event) in.readObject();
                    executeEvent(event.getFromID(), event.getTimestamp());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(timestamp);
            }
            log.write("Finished Reading");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // execute the event
        private void executeEvent(int from, Vector<Integer> x) {
            int temp;
            synchronized (timestamp) {
                for (int i = 0; i < timestamp.size(); ++i) {
                    if (x.get(i) > timestamp.get(i)) {
                        timestamp.set(i, x.get(i));
                    }
                }
                temp = timestamp.get(from);
                ++temp;
                timestamp.set(from, temp);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Controller.java

```
package timetableexchange;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Controller {

    // Mutex Lock
    public final static Object lock = new Object();

    // Constant system capacity
    static final int MAX_SYSTEMS = 4;

    // Server connection threads to computers
    static ArrayList<ServerConnection> conns = new ArrayList<ServerConnection>();

    // Finished computers
    static int finishedCount = 0;

    // Server Socket
    ServerSocket ss;

    // Log Instance
    Log log;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Controller(8000);
    }

    public Controller(int port) {
        // Instantiate Log
        log = new Log("server.txt");
        // Instantiate Server Socket and Listen for Incoming Sockets
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            log.write("Listening...");
            // Accept computers until capacity
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SYSTEMS; i++) {
                Socket s = ss.accept();
                log.write("Socket connected");
                // Add to list
                ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(i, s);
                conns.add(conn);
                conn.start();
            }
            // Notify all waiting threads to start
            synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); 
                    lock.notifyAll();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class ServerConnection extends Thread {

        // Client Socket
        Socket socket;

        // Output stream
        PrintWriter out;

        // Input stream
        BufferedReader in;

        // ID for connected computer
        int identifier;

        public ServerConnection(int i, Socket s) {
            // Instantiate properties
            this.identifier = i;
            this.socket = s;
            try {
                this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                this.out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            log.write("Controller is connected to computer#" + identifier);
            // Send ID to computer
            out.println(identifier);
            // Wait until notified
            synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // Send Start Message to All Computers
            sendAll("Start");

            waitForFinish();

            log.write("Computer#" + identifier + " is waiting for tear down.");

            // If all computers sent the Finish message, send a Tear Down
            while (true) {
                if (finishedCount == conns.size()) {
                    log.write("Sending tear down to all computers");
                    sendAll("Tear Down");
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * ==== RECEIVE FINISH MESSAGE FROM COMPUTERS ======
         */
        private void waitForFinish() {
            String clientInput;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if (in.ready()) {
                        clientInput = in.readLine();
                        log.write(clientInput);
                        if (clientInput.equals("Finish")) {
                            finishedCount += 1;
                            log.write("Computer " + identifier + " is finished");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        // Send all "text" to all computers in the thread pool
        private void sendAll(String text) {
            for (int i = 0; i < conns.size(); ++i) {
                ServerConnection conn = conns.get(i);
                conn.out.println(text);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Controller Log: (notice that the log does not say computer 3 is finished)

```
Listening... (Listening for Computer)
Socket connected
Controller is connected to computer#0
Socket connected
Controller is connected to computer#1
Socket connected
Controller is connected to computer#2
Socket connected
Controller is connected to computer#3
Computer 2 is finished
Computer 1 is finished
Computer#2 is waiting for tear down.
Computer 0 is finished
Computer#1 is waiting for tear down.
Computer#0 is waiting for tear down.
```

Computer #0 Log: (I cut down the log because there was a lot of reading and writing event log statements)

```
Computer is starting!
Server Socket Instantiated
Client Socket Created
Client Socket Created
Client Socket Created
Client Sockets Instantiated

Server connected to clients
// A bunch of reading and writing events
Finished writing. Continue reading...
Sent Finish Message 0
```

Computer #1 Log:

```
Computer is starting!
Server Socket Instantiated
Client Socket Created
Client Socket Created
Client Socket Created
Client Sockets Instantiated

Server connected to clients
Finished writing. Continue reading...
Sent Finish Message 1
```

Computer #2

```
Computer is starting!
Server Socket Instantiated
Client Socket Created
Client Socket Created
Client Socket Created
Client Sockets Instantiated

Reading events
Server connected to clients
Finished writing. Continue reading...
Sent Finish Message 2
```

Computer #3: According to the log, this sent the finished message to controller

```
Computer is starting!
Server Socket Instantiated
Client Socket Created
Client Socket Created
Client Socket Created
Client Sockets Instantiated

Reading events
Server connected to clients
Finished writing. Continue reading...
Sent Finish Message 3
```

Comment: Why each Controller's thread sends a "Start" to each Computer? That means each computer receives 4 "Start"s. That looks like a bug.

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel each thread in the controller will send a start message to each computer. so each of them will only have 1 start message.